# Calculating UV coordinates from desired texture size

Tags: opengl, glsl

Let's say I have an untextured plane made of 4 vertices. The UV coordinates of the vertices are the following:

```
(0,0)------------------(1,0)
  |                      |
  |                      |
  |                      |
  |                      |
(0,1)------------------(1,1)
```

I also have a texture and I want this texture to occupy X% of horizontal space on the plane and Y% of vertical space. How can I calculate the uv coordinate in the vertex shader to allow these arbitrary numbers?

I understand that if I want the texture to be (50%,50%) of the plane I need to make `uvCoords * 2f`, and if I want (200%,200%) then I'll need `uvCoords / 2f`, but how to do that for any number?

Comment: You just did that for any number, `uvCoords` is a variable. Is your problem that you do not understand how to convert a percentage to a fraction? `uvCoords / vec2 (X/100.0, Y/100.0)` will scale your texture coordinates based on two independent percentages for X and Y.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I think I overcomplicated everything in my head. Thanks for you answer, it's working as I expected now. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always scale your coordinates this way:

```
uvCoords / vec2 (X/100.0, Y/100.0)
```

This takes X and Y in terms of percentage and then divides the individual components of your `uvCoords` by the fractional representation for X and Y.

However, it is not clear exactly what version of OpenGL you are using here, whether it is the fixed-function pipeline or GLSL. If it is fixed-function, there is another thing you can consider called the texture matrix. You can use `glScalef (...)` to setup a scaling matrix while the matrix mode is `GL_TEXTURE` rather than performing this calculation when you setup your vertices. Just be sure to reset that matrix or you will scale everything's texture coordinates.

User texture matrices can also be used to transform texture coordinates in GLSL, though are probably more tedious to setup than doing what I suggested originally. If you wanted to rotate or translate these coordinates in addition to scaling, then I might suggest using a texture matrix.